# Delete only Specific key in a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am new to json and javascript, I have below input:

```
    var input= {
    "careerLevelGroups": [
        {
            "201801": 58,
            "201802": 74,
            "careerLevel": "Analyst",
            "careerLevels": [
                {
                    "201801": 29,
                    "201802": 37,
                    "careerID": "10000100"
                },
                {
                    "201801": 29,
                    "201802": 37,
                    "careerID": "10000110"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "201801": 58,
            "201802": 74,
            "careerLevel": "Consultant",
            "careerLevels": [
                {
                    "201801": 29,
                    "201802": 37,
                    "careerID": "10000080"
                },
                {
                    "201801": 29,
                    "201802": 37,
                    "careerID": "10000090"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I need to create this result:

```
    var result = {
  [

        {
           "careerLevel": "Analyst",
            "careerLevels": [
                {
                    "201801": 29,
                    "201802": 37,
                    "careerID": "10000100"
                },
                {
                    "201801": 29,
                    "201802": 37,
                    "careerID": "10000110"
                }
            ]
        },
        {

            "careerLevel": "Consultant",
            "careerLevels": [
                {
                    "201801": 29,
                    "201802": 37,
                    "careerID": "10000080"
                },
                {
                    "201801": 29,
                    "201802": 37,
                    "careerID": "10000090"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I think i need to do something like where in i  only need careerLevel and careerLevels attributes (rest all should be deleted). I tried the loop structure and delete command for json but iam not getting the right format.

```
 let clJson = input.careerLevelGroups.forEach(element => {
  let keysToDelete = Object.keys(element).filter( // return keys with careerLevel and careerLevels);
 // delete keys

});
```

Comment: Your result (`result = { [ .... ] }`) is not a legal object.  Should its one property retain the name "careerLevelGroups"  (`result = { careerLevelGroups: [ .... ] }`)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `delete` operator to delete keys:

```js
var input = {
  "careerLevelGroups": [{
      "201801": 58,
      "201802": 74,
      "careerLevel": "Analyst",
      "careerLevels": [{
          "201801": 29,
          "201802": 37,
          "careerID": "10000100"
        },
        {
          "201801": 29,
          "201802": 37,
          "careerID": "10000110"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "201801": 58,
      "201802": 74,
      "careerLevel": "Consultant",
      "careerLevels": [{
          "201801": 29,
          "201802": 37,
          "careerID": "10000080"
        },
        {
          "201801": 29,
          "201802": 37,
          "careerID": "10000090"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const result = input.careerLevelGroups;
result.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (key !== 'careerLevel' && key !== 'careerLevels') delete obj[key];
  })
});
console.log(result);
```

Do note that this mutates the original object - it doesn't create a copy.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution seems to be one that uses object destructuring:

```js
const input= {"careerLevelGroups": [{"201801": 58, "201802": 74, "careerLevel": "Analyst", "careerLevels": [{"201801": 29, "201802": 37, "careerID": "10000100"}, {"201801": 29, "201802": 37, "careerID": "10000110"}]}, {"201801": 58, "201802": 74, "careerLevel": "Consultant", "careerLevels": [{"201801": 29, "201802": 37, "careerID": "10000080"}, {"201801": 29, "201802": 37, "careerID": "10000090"}]}]}

const simplify = ({careerLevel, careerLevels}) => ({careerLevel, careerLevels})
const result = {careerLevelGroups: input.careerLevelGroups.map(simplify)}

console.log(result)
```

Note that the output is slightly altered from your original, which is not legal syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to remove an item "xyz" from an object "obj" is

`delete obj["xyz"];`

Comment: I need to delete the other atributes dynamically